# Local network domain resolution times out with DNSMasq, but works fine remotely

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

For some reason, I can't get this to reliably work the way I want it, across both Linux and Windows, and even across different machines running the same OS.

Let's assume I have a local machine running on `192.168.1.66` and my public IP of `107.214.228.39` is simply forwarding all ports to that local machine via the router.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to simply resolve a FQDN regardless of whether I am local or remote. For example, trying to load `home.trwnh.com` should do a DNS lookup and see that the address is `192.168.1.66` when I am on my local network with DNSMasq running, and `107.214.228.39` when I am remote and using e.g. Google or Cloudflare DNS.

This has worked at times and failed at other times, for no reason that I can understand. Generally what will happen is that DNSMasq seems to be working in resolving the FQDN to the local IP of `192.168.1.66`, but then the actual loading of the webpage seems to time out. Firefox tells me "The connection has timed out: The server at home.trwnh.com is taking too long to respond." Likewise with attempting to load the website by FQDN on the actual host machine, it resolves properly to localhost but still fails to load the website.

What am I doing wrong?

Configs here: https://gist.github.com/trwnh/c61e1b0988c0ae7e68ef19a2426a9cd2

---

EDIT: Curiouser and curiouser! I just found out that Chrome works just fine, and this issue is only happening in Firefox...

EDIT 2: Turned off DNS over HTTPS and Firefox works now.

EDIT 3: Have not confirmed this for myself, but https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/canary-domain-use-application-dnsnet indicates I should add `local=/use-application-dns.net/` to my /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: In all your text you dig not specify how you tested DNS resolution. Indeed you shouldn't use a browser to test that but low level tools like `dig` with its `@` option. Browsers implement DoH now, and other applications can too, each one with its own policy and configuration settings, so that makes troubleshooting issues not suitable in a browser.

Comment: remind that use-application-dns.net is a valid domain